# How to change background color of UILocalizedIndexedCollation in ios 7

Tags: ios, ios7

In the IOS 7 UILocalizedIndexedCollation are looking very odd and i would like to customise the background color and text color, i have googled everywhere but no success, If somebody able to get something on this please help me

Comment: `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` isn't a view, how can you change its color? Perhaps you mean the various `sectionIndex...` properties of `UITableView`.

Comment: is there any way to subclass or extend into a view because it look so odd with white color in ios

Comment: Did you look at the properties I referenced?

Comment: Yes, thanks you very much for "Properties"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    self.tableView.sectionIndexColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    self.tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

this truly help by "rmaddy"

Answer (score 0):

UILocalizedIndexedCollation has no public properties for setting its appearance, which means that you cannot customize it in a direct way.

Comment: What do you mean "suddenly"? It never did.